# Check data type format of every value of a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a `table_1` that has column `dob` which has datatype `nvarchar(max)`. Now I want to check every date whether it is in `datetime` format or not.

The dates which are in `datetime` format should be copied to `table_2` that has column with a datatype of `datetime`.

Any help how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, then `TRY_CONVERT` can help here:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(datetime, dob) IS NULL;
```

This would return every record from your table where the `dob` text field is in some format which SQL Server cannot natively convert to a datetime.

Comment: Although this is correct one should never rely on the plain convert or cast. when dealing with date and/or time values. I'd always specify the style parameter in `CONVERT`...

Comment: @Shnugo Well I must confess, your answer has a bit more _style_ than mine does `:P`

Answer (score 0):

This will insert all the strings can be converted into `Table_2`

```
INSERT INTO Table_2 (DateTimeColumn)
SELECT dob
FROM Table_1
WHERE TRY_CAST(dob AS DATETIME) IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Although this is correct one should never rely on the plain cast. when dealing with date and/or time values. I'd always use `CONVERT` together with the style parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very bad habit to store datetime values in a string. The reason why: Date-Time formats differ around the world and depend on your system's culture settings. Even worse, some format depend on a given language. Try this out:

```sql
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH; --try with GERMAN to see the effect on "Decemeber"
SET DATEFORMAT ymd;   --try with "ydm" or "dmy"

DECLARE @tbl TABLE(dob NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('blah')             --just a wrong value
                      ,('20201231')         --ISO, "unseparated YMD-format (see CONVERT with 112)
                      ,('2020-12-31')       --ISO8601
                      ,('2020-31-12')       --European with leading year
                      ,('12-31-2020')       --USA (see CONVERT with 110)
                      ,('31-12-2020')       --European (see CONVERT with 113)
                      ,('31 December 2020') --language dependant (see CONVERT with 113), try with German "Dezember" 
                      ,('2020-02-30');      --Invalid, there's no 30th of February

SELECT t.dob                                                                  --Your value 
      ,[cast]    = TRY_CAST(t.dob AS DATETIME)                                --CAST relies on the system's settings (might work on your machine but can break on a customer's machine
      ,[convert] = TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, t.dob, 112)                          --CONVERT allows to use the style paramter, better than CAST, but more strict
      ,[parse]   = TRY_PARSE(t.dob AS DATETIME USING 'en-US')                 --Parsing allows to mention the culture. You do not need to specify the language as a general setting
      ,[xmlCast] = CAST(t.dob AS XML).value('. cast as xs:date?','datetime')  --Works below v2012, but can deal with ISO8601 only.
FROM @tbl t;
```

### Play with the settings

You can use `GERMAN` instead of `ENGLISH`. The entry with `December` will not work any more. You can change the general date format to any combination of `ymd` and find, that some formats stop to work while others start to work.

`TRY_CAST`, `TRY_CONVERT` and `TRY_PARSE` will need a version of v2012 or higher.

If you are running an older system you should upgrade ( :-) ). The only chance with an older system is a XML hack, but this is very tightly bound to ISO8601.

Finally: For your next question, please try to add more information. State some of your input values, mention your RDBMS with version and try to set up a *mockup* with DDL and INSERT (look what I've done above).

### Hint: Very dangerous...

Try to insert a value like `2020-05-06` and you will find, that some styles read this as the 5th of June, while others return the 6th of May. Returning **wrong values is worse** than returning NULL or throwing an error...

StayAtHome
StayHealthy